# Xcode SDL resources folder

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, sdl, sdl-image

I am making a SDL project in Xcode and I have a folder called resources where my images are stored. For my SDL application to access these images with SDL_LoadBMP the resources folder needs to be in the same folder as the executable file. I don't want to have to copy and paste my resources into the "/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SDL_app-awvygturnguyeqgwpjowmouadbjf/Build/Products/Debug" folder every time I want to run an application (I don't know why all the random characters are in the folder link). I have been following Lazy Foo's first SDL tutorial: http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson01/index2.php and I am trying to display an image on the screen. I don't need to show my code in here because it is the exact same as the tutorial I linked to except instead of SDL_LoadBMP("hello.bmp") it is SDL_LoadBMP("resources/images/hello.bmp"). The application works as soon as I copy the resources folder into the product directory. I was going to show an image of the folder and so on but I didn't have enough 'reputation'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to make sure the folder gets copied, you need to add the folder to your Xcode project and then create a Copy step in your Build Phases.   By default, there is a Copy Phase for items that are identified as Resources by the system (.strings files, .xib files, etc.)   However, for additional files, you'll need to create a Copy Phase specifically.

To do this:

1. In Xcode, select your project and Target and choose the `Build Phases` tab
2. Click on the `Add Build Phase` button and choose `Add Copy Files`
3. Select the `Destination` location for the copy (this is the "top" of the hierarchy, you can also specify sub-directories using the `Subpath` field)
4. Now drag the folders or files from the Project Navigator into the new Copy Phase

When you build your executable, the files will be copied as you direct them.

If your SDL files are being modified outside of Xcode, you may want to import the folder as a Folder Reference instead of as individual files.   This can be a little tricky, but it causes Xcode to copy the current contents of the folder, as opposed to just the items that you've added to the Project.   Otherwise, just import the SDL files directly into the Xcode project and manage them individually.

Comment: Thankyou for the help, is there anyway of actually having the resources packed inside the application file so the result only has one file (e.g. iMovie.app). The product isn't one of those packages (.app), the file type is Unix Executable.

Comment: That's a bit of a different question and you might want to ask it separately, but I am not aware of a way to do that automatically.   If the data is all read-only, you could use some kind of multi-file format and append the data to your executable in a DATA segment and read it from disk either at launch or by opening another read-only channel to the executable files with an offset to that DATA segment, but that's a really complex solution.

Comment: hmm maybe I will ask another question because I wonder how for example GIMP has all of it's application contents stuck in one nice little .app file, actually if you go 'Show Package Contents' you can browse around the archive and find the 'Unix Executable File'. I think .app is similar to a .jar (java archive) file for Java.

Comment: OK, I thought you were indicating that you didn't **want** it to be in an `.app` file.   At this point, it sounds like you are trying to to create a `.app` file wrapper for a Unix Executable, right?   It's not that different from how cocoa works, just a little more work.   If you make a different question about this, I can look into that as well, I think we have some cases where we've done this.